# Is there a word for someone or something that literally defies the laws of physics?

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a substance called '[Magic Sand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_sand)' (hydrophobic sand) that stays 100% dry when taken out from underneath water. It isn't a trick but nature therefore technically not magic

I'm an atheist that also doesn't believe in any type of deity what so ever. If a person develops magic-like abilities self taught, that isn't magic.I'm fully aware the odds of another believer are slim but I thought perhaps I'd find a person who would agree with me or atleast be just as curious so I gave this question a shot.

Answer (score 3):

***[Supernatural](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/supernatural)***

> (Of a manifestation or event) attributed to some force beyond scientific understanding or the laws of nature

(OED)

---

If you don't like *supernatural*, how about ***[miraculous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/miraculous)*** or ***seemingly [miraculous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/miraculous)***?

> 1. Of the nature of a miracle or having the power to work miracles
> 2. Remarkable and bringing very welcome consequences

(OED)

Comment: A more sophisticated word please?

Comment: ... Hypermundane.

Comment: Please explain how this word lacks sophistication. Please edit your answer so that your requirements are crystal clear.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I believe it is *extramundane*.

Comment: @CaseyAffleck You say "more sophisticated"; are you actually looking for something without negative connotations?

Comment: _Hypermundane_ is 32% more sophisticated than _extramundane_ (rarity value). But I'm about to downvote as OP asks for 'Such a thing that isn't caused by magic'. Jim has the right idea.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Haha, fair enough.

Comment: @Casey Affleck Are you saying that nothing outside the sphere/s of human understanding exists? That takes a lot of faith. In yourself.

Answer (score 1):

### Nonexistent

There is nothing that *literally* defies the laws of physics.  There are things which *appear* to defy the laws of physics, but these fall into one of two categories:

1. The mechanism behind the phenomenon is not fully understood (either due to simple misinterpretation of the manifestations of the phenomenon or due to incomplete understanding of the laws of physics)
2. The phenomenon is a fake

Comment: agreed.  When human laws are broken, the law-breaker is punished.  When a law of physics is broken, the law is changed.  'Law' actually means two different things in those two cases.

Answer (score 0):

***Mystical***

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mystical): Having a spiritual meaning or reality that is neither apparent to the senses nor obvious to the intelligence: *the mystical food of the sacrament*.

[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mystical): Inspiring a sense of spiritual mystery, awe, and fascination: *the mystical forces of nature*.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mystical): Of or relating to supernatural agencies, affairs, occurrences, etc.: *a strange, mystical experience*.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on context, I can suggest:

**scientifically puzzling** - The sand should be wet but isn't and nobody can explain why.

**a thought provoking result**

**an illusion** - The sand is dry simply because that specific kind of sand is hydrophobic and nobody raised or even thought of this possibility.

**"It's magic!"**  Until we find a scientific explanation.

The human being has a tendency to mystify or say that something is magic when no explanation or theory can be brought up.  Time often proves them wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A sophisticated word that means something defies the laws of physics (or at least our expectations)?

How about **Thaumaturgic**.

You could say that Steve Spangler is a **thaumaturgist** and his hydrophobic sand is pure **thaumaturgy**.

Comment: As thaumaturgy is defined as 'The working of miracles or magic feats' by [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thaumaturgic), I don't think OP will like this.

Comment: I may be off on what the OP wants. I thought the OP wanted a sophisticated word for something or someone that appears to defy the laws of physics, i.e. a miracle or miracle-worker.

Comment: I think he mainly wants to get across his view that science is God. _And I thought materialism was dead!_

Answer (score 0):

Something that defies the laws of physics is **impossible**.

It sounds though, that this thing doesn't defy the laws of physics at all, more likely, it defies our intuitive sense of the world.

For example this [Quantum Levitation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ws6AAhTw7RA) appears to be a trick or impossible, but is real and perfectly within the laws of physics.

You might simply call this **trippy**

Definition:

> resembling or inducing the hallucinatory effect produced by taking a psychedelic drug.

Heh. :D

Or simply **defying ordinary expectations**. *Ordinary* being the operative word here.  A scientist working on the substance probably wouldn't see this as 'magical' at all, but the layman would.

Answer (score 0):

With the edit, it becomes simpler.

Such results are **paradoxical**:

> paradox n.
>
> 2. A person, thing, or situation that exhibits inexplicable or [apparently] contradictory aspects

[[AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/paradoxical)]

Comment: magic sand or quantum levitation isn't paradoxical at all, because there's no _actual_ contradiction.

Comment: @dwjohnston You need to look in a dictionary before leaping into error, eg [WordNet 3.0, Farlex clipart collection. © 2003-2012 Princeton University, Farlex Inc.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/paradoxical): **paradoxical**: seemingly contradictory but nonetheless possibly true